# append an atom with exisiting variables and create new set in clingo

Tags: answer-set-programming, clingo

I am totally new in asp, I am learning clingo and I have a problem with variables. I am working on graphs and paths in the graphs so I used a tuple such as `g((1,2,3))`. what I want is to add new node to the path in which the tuple sequence holds. for instance the code below will give me `(0, (1,2,3))` but what I want is `(0,1,2,3)`.
Thanks in advance.

```
g((1,2,3)).
g((0,X)):-g(X).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naive fix:

```
g((0,X,Y,Z)) :- g((X,Y,Z)).
```

However I sense that you want to store the path in the tuple as is it is a list. Bad news: unlike prolog clingo isn't meant to handle lists as terms of atoms (like your example does). Lists are handled by indexing the elements, for example the list `[a,b,c]` would be stored in predicates like `p(1,a). p(2,b). p(3,c).`. Why? Because of grounding: you aim to get a small ground program to reduce the complexity of the solving process. To put it in numbers: assuming you are searching for a path which includes all `n` nodes. This sums up to `n!`. For `n=10` this are 3628800 potential paths, introducing 3628800 predicates for a comparively small graph. Numbering the nodes as mentioned will lead to only `n*n` potential predicates to represent the path. For `n=10` these are just 100, in comparison to 3628800 a huge gain.

To get an impression what you are searching for, run the following example derived from the [potassco](https://potassco.org/clingo/run/) website:

```
% generating path: for every time exactly one node
{ path(T,X) : node(X) } = 1 :- T=1..6. 
% one node isn't allowed on two different positions
:- path(T1,X), path(T2,X), T1!=T2. 
% there has to be an edge between 2 adjascent positions
:- path(T,X), path(T+1,Y), not edge(X,Y). 
#show path/2.

% Nodes
node(1..6).
% (Directed) Edges
edge(1,(2;3;4)).  edge(2,(4;5;6)).  edge(3,(1;4;5)).
edge(4,(1;2)).    edge(5,(3;4;6)).  edge(6,(2;3;5)).
```

Output:

```
Answer: 1
path(1,1) path(2,3) path(3,4) path(4,2) path(5,5) path(6,6)
Answer: 2
path(1,1) path(2,3) path(3,5) path(4,4) path(5,2) path(6,6)
Answer: 3
path(1,6) path(2,2) path(3,5) path(4,3) path(5,4) path(6,1)
Answer: 4
path(1,1) path(2,4) path(3,2) path(4,5) path(5,6) path(6,3)
Answer: 5
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. In fact, I am using Clingo for a non-monotonic problem. My grounder is the edges and shortest paths from all nodes to a certain node which I created separately with python. Sometimes when some condition holds, I need to make a detour in the existing path and add it to a set of paths. for example, if the shortest path is g((2,0)) from node 2 to 0. sometimes I need to create a longer path like g((2,1,0)) :- r((1,0)) that's why I needed to make g((n, X)):-r(X) work somehow. (n is the current node)